Proving that a subset of a countable set must be either countable or finite
This is an attempted proof using the textbook Stephen Abbott
For exercise 1.5.1

Theorem 1.5.7: if $A \subseteq {B}$ where $B$ is countable. then $A$ must be either countable or finite

Exercise:
Continue with the given hypothesis to complete the proof for theorem 1.5.7.
Assume $B$ is a countable set thus exists $f: N \to B$
Let $A\subseteq B$ be an infinite subset of $B$. We must show that $A$ is countable
Let $n_1=\min\{n\in{\mathbb{N}}, f(n)\in A\}$
As a start to definition of $g:\mathbb{N} \to B$, set $g(1)=f(n_1)$
Finish the proof
Define the set:
\begin{equation}
    a_n:=\min\{f(n)\in{A},f(n)\neq {a_m}| \forall m < n \ \text{and } n, m\in{\mathbb{N}}\} \\
\end{equation}
Given that $A$ is assumed by question to be infinite, and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by well-ordering principle $a_n$ is then well-defined with the property:
\begin{equation}
    a_n<a_{n+1} \text{and  }  \ n\neq{m} \ \  , a_n\neq{a_m}
\end{equation}
Define the property of g:
$\forall{g(n)}\in{A}$  ,$\exists{n} \Rightarrow a_n = g(n)$
We then aim to show that $g$ is onto. Claim for the sake of contradiction that $\exists{g(n)} \neq a_n$ then by previous definition implies $ g(n)\in \{f(n)\in{A},f(n)\neq {a_m}| \forall m < n, n\in{\mathbb{N}}\}$ This clearly leads to contradiction since $a_n$ is increasing and the derivation led to $g(n)\geq{a_n} \Rightarrow g(n+1)=a_{n+1}<g(n)=a_n$
[]
This clearly shows that for some natural number $n$ we have $g$ is onto.
And as the property $a_n<a_{n+1}$ reveals, $g$ is also injective hence $g$ must be a bijection
Hence we have established the equivalent relations $A \sim \mathbb{N}$ Since $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, $A$ must be also countable.
The main idea I have here is to establish the same cardinality of $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$ which will imply the countability, with the equivalent relation I will be able to show that $A$ is indeed countable.

So basically I don’t really know the correctness of the proof at all.
I will clarify a bit of my thoughts of construction of $a_n$ and why I would do so, I primarily considered that $n$ is irrelevant for $A$ here since $f: \mathbb{N} \to B$, natural number is ordered, this idea was formed by that I could just use n as some sort of indices or marker to derive an abstract sequence of $f$ and since $a_n$ is really indexed by $n\in\mathbb{N}$ I felt like it should hold, by doing this I implicitly considered $B$ as natural number set, since it is arbitrary, by indexing $n$ I used the marker to reorder the entire sequence all in once. Sorry if my language wasn't very clear because it had been my second analysis lecture and I felt very unhappy at school due to my classmates weren't nice to me, so I couldn't focus and learn the terminology

Just looking at the definition, what is $A$?  What is $f$?  What's $g$?   I think sorting out the definitions will clarify a lot.

I was trying to use the property of f as bijection to construct a recursive relation which is a function in A, if I can create a well-ordered set with the outlined then I could leverage it to show g is bijective in such way, then I show that A is a subset of N since B is countable and A is a countable infinite set.. that was my idea

In your proof you take $a_n = \text{min}{f(n)\in A : etc}$, however this values only if $A$ (or $B$) is ordered, which, I believe, is not part of the hypothesis.

We have no idea what $A$ or $f$ are.  Please edit your post to explain what they are.  For proofs like this, getting the definitions straight is critical.  Even if $A$ has some order, which seems implied by what you wrote, though you don't say it, that doesn't mean that every subset of $A$ has a minimum.

@PauloEstêvão the idea is that f is a bijection f:N->B I thought I can leverage this. Though I am not absolutely convinced

@lulu please click the link question

Questions here should be reasonably self contained.  We should not have to open links to sort out what you are asking.  In any case, it might be a useful exercise to write out the assumed properties of the terms you are using.

@lulu I will write it out immediately!

I understand the idea, I'm just pointing that there is a problem with the definition of the sequence $(a_n)$, because it suppose $A$ is ordered and $f(n) < f(m)$ is defined

@PauloEstêvão The main part I was uncertain is that the ordering argument, I was unsure if I could leverage the property directly of N, which I thought to be valid, because f is bijection. I felt the indices will not lead to lesser rigor, because f is inherently bijection. which was the reason though I specifically mentioned that $n\in \mathbb{N}$, though I am still unsure though. Since I wasnt saying A or B was well ordered

Yeah let $S_1=\{n\in\mathbb{N}|f(n)\in A\}$. Thanks to the well ordering of Natural Numbers this set has a minimum and we call it $n_1$. Define $S_2=S_1\setminus \{n_1\}$, this set is surely not empty because if not $S_1=\{n_1\}$ and then you would have $A=\{f(n_1)\}$ because $f$ is bijective and this is absurd because $A$ is not finite. So exist $n_2$ the minimum of $S_2$. Inductively define $S_{k+1}=S_1\setminus\{n_1,\dots, n_k\}$. This set is not empty because if not you would have $S_{1}=\{n_1,\dots,n_k\}$ and this is impossible because $f$ is bijective and $A$ is infinite. So we have $n_i=\operatorname{min}S_i, \forall i\in\mathbb{N}$ and construct $g(i)=f(n_i)$. This function is 1-1 because $i\neq j\implies i>j$ or $j>i$. Wlog if $i>j$ $n_i\in S_i$ and $S_i=S_1\setminus\{n_{i-1},\dots,n_j,\dots,n_1\}$, so $n_i\neq n_j$ and since $f$ is bijective you have done.

This does not show that $g$ is surjective, or am I missing something?

I'm not understanding, $f$ is from $N$ to $B$, how do you compose it with $i$?

Ok, now I get it, it should be $f\of i$, however you don't really need CB, I gave a proof that does not rely on that

@SamueleBiscaro you can consider the immersion $i\colon A\rightarrow B$ and $f^{-1}\colon B\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. $f^{-1}$ is bi and $i$ is 1-1 so the composition is 1-1. Thanks to C-S-B you have done. In the previous comment i've erroneously inverted the arrows without using the proper notation.

The idea is correct, however you need to be careful in showing that $g$ is onto. I will just for clarity write the whole proof, even if the first part of your proof is correct.
We have $f:\mathbb N \to B$ a bijection and $A\subseteq B$, we wish to build a $g:\mathbb N \to A$ that is bijective, so that $A$ is also countable.
We start by defining $n_0 = \min\{n\in \mathbb N \text{ such that } f(n)\in A\}$, which is well defined since $f$ is surjective so the set we're taking the minimum of is non empty. Then by induction we can define
$$
n_{k+1} = \min\{n\in \mathbb N \text{ such that } f(n)\in A\ \text{ and } n > n_k\}.
$$
Again, this is well defined since $A$ is infinite, so the above set is non empty (remember that any infinite subset of $\mathbb N$ is unbounded).
We now can construct $g:\mathbb N \to A$ defining $g(k) = f(n_k)$ for every $k$, by construction if $n\neq m$ then $g(n) \neq g(m)$ (as you said in your proof, since $f(n_k)$ is more or less what you tried to define $a_k$).
For showing that $g$ is surjective we proceed as follow.
Let $a\in A$ such that $g(k)\neq a$ for every $k\in \mathbb N$, then, since $f$ is surjective, there exists $m$ such that $f(m) = a$, also since $n_k$ is increasing it is eventually bigger than $m$, so that there exists the minimum $l$ such that $n_l > m$. Note that $l \neq 0$, since $n_0$ is the minimum such that $f(n_0)\in A$ and $f(m ) = a \in A$. But note that $n_{l-1} < m$ and, with a very similar argument, we get a contradiction since
$$
n_{l} = \min\{n\in \mathbb N \text{ such that } f(n)\in A\ \text{ and } n > n_{l-1}\}.
$$
but $m < n_{l}$ is in that set.
So we get that $g$ is a bijection, as desired.

Hi, your proof is great, it took me some moment to grapes the element of your proof. I am new to analysis (only had two lectures), I want to know a bit further, what I did wrong because for surjectivity proof, I think it took me too long to come up with the proof I want to know as many details as possible.. Because I wasnt sure why I have to define $g(k)=f(n_k)$

The main part I was uncertain is that the ordering argument, I was unsure if I could leverage the property directly of N, which I thought to be valid, because f is bijection. I felt the indices will not lead to lesser rigor, because f is inherently bijection. which was the reason though I specifically mentioned that $n\in \mathbb{N}, though I am still unsure though. I will adapt your way to refine my proof, because it led confusion already for someone also comment about it.
